# Server sent event not working Spring Boot Webflux

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I have this simple method which listens for Redis Pub/Sub message and emits Server sent event but for some reason it is not working. This is what I have.

```
@GetMapping
fun getNotifications(@RequestParam(name = "token", required = true) token: String): Flux<ServerSentEvent<Notification>> {

    if (token.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return Flux.error(ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token"))
    }

    val claims = jwtService.getAllClaimsFromToken(token) ?: return Flux.error(ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token"))
    val userName = jwtService.getUsernameFromToken(claims) ?: return Flux.error(ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token"))

    return userRepository.findOneByEmail(userName)
                .filter { user -> checkAccess(user) }
                .thenMany<ServerSentEvent<Notification>> {
                    notificationService.subscribe()
                        .map { ServerSentEvent.builder<Notification>()
                                   .event("notification")
                                   .data(it)
                                   .build() 
                             }.asFlux()
                }.switchIfEmpty {
                    Flux.error<ResponseStatusException>(ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Token expired"))
                }
}

private fun checkAccess(user: User): Boolean {

    if (!user.enabled || !user.account.enabled) {
        return false
    }

    /// More checking... logic

    return true
}
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: try not subscribing, instead use `flatMap` you are not the consumer, the endclient is the consumer.

Comment: I am sorry would you please explain where you want me to use flatMap?

Comment: `notificationService.subscribe()` try `notificationService.flatMap { ... }`. Your application is a producer. It produces data to a consumer. The consumer is the calling client. So the consumer subscribes. If your application was the final destination for something, then it would the consumer. But as i can see it just relays data from redis to a consumer (the calling client) so you should not be subscribing.

Comment: Here `subscribe` is the custom method that I created. It is not reactive method. Under the hood `subscribe` does this. `redisOperations.listenToChannelAsFlow(RedisConfiguration.CHANNEL_NAME).map { it.message }`

Comment: its very hard to know, im suspecting you are breaking the chain, but its very hard to figure out where since i cant see your return values.